# more than one primary key error in django

Tags: django, migration, key

I have a problem with two of my models. When tying to migrate it always ends up with the error that I have more than one primary key. I have googled and tried lots of different solutions but nothing works.

models: notice the imports

```
from django.db.models import Model,CharField,EmailField,IntegerField,\
     OneToOneField,CASCADE,DateTimeField,ForeignKey,BooleanField,\
     IntegerField,SlugField
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from phone_field import PhoneField
from datetime import datetime
from pdb import set_trace as B

class Adress(Model):

    street=CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    snumb=CharField(default='',max_length=15)
    town=CharField(default='',max_length=100)
    postn=CharField(default='',max_length=5,validators=[postnvali])
    
    def __str__(self):
        return 'city: ' + self.town

    class Meta:
        ordering=('street','town')

class Person(Model):

    fname=CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    lname=CharField(default="",max_length=100)
    mobil=PhoneField(default='9999999999')
    mail=EmailField(default='contact@gmail.com')
    padress=OneToOneField(Adress,on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'person: ' + self.fname

    class Meta:
        ordering=('fname','lname')
```

migration file:

```
# Generated by Django 3.1.4 on 2021-01-20 13:32

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('kammem', '0029_auto_20210120_1354'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='person',
            name='id',
            field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True,serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='person',
            name='padress',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='kammem.adress'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: Your migrations say that you are adding a field `id` to your `Person` model, that field already exists along with a field `pk` which can be both used as primary keys, is it not in your actual model? And can you show the full error traceback?

Comment: it is not in my model.

Comment: show the traceback then

Comment: short error traceback: (cannotpost the whole)
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "new__kammem_person" has more than one primary key

Comment: posted it below

Comment: you can actually edit your own questions, next time do that :) I'll check it out

Comment: sorry mate have no clue whats the issue here, try deleting ALL your migrations then run them again, clearly when you migrate you're adding an AutoField which is a field type that makes itself primary key on default and that is what is the cause of your error is, why is it adding it I don't know though, doesn't look like you have it in any of your models

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your **migration file** to this and then run `migrate`:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('kammem', '0029_auto_20210120_1354'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='person',
            name='padress',
            field=models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to='kammem.adress'),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: that gives the same error:
 return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "new__kammem_person" has more than one primary key

Comment: are the models that in the question right now the exact same ones that you have in your code?

Comment: one more thing I noticed your models dont inherit from django `models.Model` base class, try changing that and plus in your relations where you have `on_delete=models.CASCADE` also add it

Comment: they do, I included the imports in the above models for clarity

Comment: try deleting your migrations and then making and migrating again

Comment: same error.... first it ask for a default value, and then "table "new__kammem_person" has more than one primary key" error

Comment: Add the full error traceback to your question please

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is the full error traceback:

```
jonas@192.168.1.133 kammem $ python3 manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, kammem, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying kammem.0025_auto_20210120_0935...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table "new__kammem_person" has more than one primary key

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jonas/Dropbox/prog/web/django/kammem/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/jonas/Dropbox/prog/web/django/kammem/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 85, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 243, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 236, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 138, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 571, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 360, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 280, in _remake_table
    self.create_model(new_model)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 324, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 142, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
  File "/home/jonas/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 411, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "new__kammem_person" has more than one primary key
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I solved it by simply removing all migrationsfiles and then rerun make migrations and migrate. Still, this is a common problem according to my google searches.